# action cable - not receiving response on client

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, react-native, real-time, actioncable

When I run my react-native mobile app, the server says it connects to the PostChannel. It creates the post, however I get no response in the 'received' function so it does not update in real time.

This is my react-native code:

```
import ActionCable from 'react-native-actioncable';
const APP = {};
APP.cable = ActionCable.createConsumer("http://localhost:3000/cable");

const addSocket = (dispatch) => {
  const self = this;
  this.subscription = APP.cable.subscriptions.create(
    "PostChannel",
  {
    connected: () => {
      console.log("connected: action cable");
    },
    disconnected: () => {
      console.log("disconnected: action cable");
    },
    received: (data) => {
      console.log('received', data);     // no response here
      dispatch(receivePost(data.post));
    }
  });
};
```

Rails code:

Channel

```
class PostChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    stream_from "post_channel"
  end
end
```

Model

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  validates :user_id, :venue_id, presence: true

  after_create_commit { PostBroadcastJob.perform_later self}

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :venue
end
```

Job

```
class PostBroadcastJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform(post)
    ActionCable.server.broadcast 'post_channel', render_post(post)
  end

  private
  def render_post(post)
    ApplicationController.renderer.render post
  end
end
```

post partial

```
json.id post.id
json.body post.body
json.author post.author.username
json.timestamp time_ago_in_words(post.created_at)
```

Here is the server log:

```
Started GET "/cable" for ::1 at 2017-04-19 21:14:36 -0700
Started GET "/cable/" [WebSocket] for ::1 at 2017-04-19 21:14:36 -0700
Successfully upgraded to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: Upgrade, HTTP_UPGRADE: websocket)
PostChannel is transmitting the subscription confirmation
PostChannel is streaming from post_channel
Started POST "/api/posts" for ::1 at 2017-04-19 21:14:43 -0700
Processing by Api::PostsController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"post"=>{"venue_id"=>4, "user_id"=>1, "body"=>"a"}}
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity.
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Venue Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "venues".* FROM "venues" WHERE "venues"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 4], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "posts" ("user_id", "venue_id", "body", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["user_id", 1], ["venue_id", 4], ["body", "a"], ["created_at", 2017-04-20 04:14:43 UTC], ["updated_at", 2017-04-20 04:14:43 UTC]]
   (2.0ms)  COMMIT
[ActiveJob] Enqueued PostBroadcastJob (Job ID: 4ebbf405-2bd7-43e9-94fc-e4f5195afc0f) to Async(default) with arguments: #<GlobalID:0x007f838d3a5d00 @uri=#<URI::GID gid://backend/Post/50>>
  Rendering api/posts/show.json.jbuilder
  Post Load (3.8ms)  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 50], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendered api/posts/show.json.jbuilder (0.9ms)
[ActiveJob] [PostBroadcastJob] [4ebbf405-2bd7-43e9-94fc-e4f5195afc0f] Performing PostBroadcastJob from Async(default) with arguments: #<GlobalID:0x007f838d35dfc8 @uri=#<URI::GID gid://backend/Post/50>>
Completed 200 OK in 34ms (Views: 6.3ms | ActiveRecord: 3.1ms)


[ActiveJob] [PostBroadcastJob] [4ebbf405-2bd7-43e9-94fc-e4f5195afc0f]   Rendered api/posts/_post.json.jbuilder (16.7ms)
[ActiveJob] [PostBroadcastJob] [4ebbf405-2bd7-43e9-94fc-e4f5195afc0f] Performed PostBroadcastJob from Async(default) in 26.05ms
```

I tried changing the Job to render the raw post:

```
  def perform(post)
    ActionCable.server.broadcast 'post_channel', post
  end
```

And the client receives the data this way. But not in the format I need. So I still need it to use the jbuilder partial. Am I rendering the partial wrong? I've tried a few different ways.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm having this problem now. Were you able to fix this?